# How does @_ work in Perl subroutines?

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference, parameter-passing, subroutine

I was always sure that if I pass a Perl subroutine a simple scalar, it can never change its value outside the subroutine. That is:

```
my $x = 100;
foo($x);
# without knowing anything about foo(), I'm sure $x still == 100
```

So if I want `foo()` to change `x`, I must pass it a reference to `x`.

Then I found out this is not the case:

```
sub foo {
 $_[0] = 'CHANGED!';
}
my $x = 100;
foo($x);
print $x, "\n"; # prints 'CHANGED!'
```

And the same goes for array elements:

```
my @arr = (1,2,3);
print $arr[0], "\n"; # prints '1'
foo($arr[0]);
print $arr[0], "\n"; # prints 'CHANGED!'
```

That kinda surprised me. How does this work? Isn't the subroutine only gets the **value** of the argument? How does it know its address?

Comment: Perl is not C.  Don't expect it to behave like C, or any C-derived language like C++ or Java.

Comment: [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

Comment: Your question is about `@_`, not `$_`.  And `@_` in a `sub` often contains aliases rather than copies of values.  So if you don't want this behavior in your `sub`, be sure to copy input from `@_` to `my` variables at the start.

Comment: I'm *quite* certain this is very well documented.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Perl, the subroutine arguments stored in `@_` are always aliases to the values at the call site.  This aliasing only persists in `@_`, if you copy values out, that's what you get, values.

so in this sub:

```
sub example {
   # @_ is an alias to the arguments
   my ($x, $y, @rest) = @_;  # $x $y and @rest contain copies of the values
   my $args = \@_;  # $args contains a reference to @_ which maintains aliases
}
```

Note that this aliasing happens after list expansion, so if you passed an array to `example`, the array expands in list context, and `@_` is set to aliases of each element of the array (but the array itself is not available to `example`).  If you wanted the latter, you would pass a reference to the array.

Aliasing of subroutine arguments is a very useful feature, but must be used with care.  To prevent unintended modification of external variables, in Perl 6 you must specify that you want writable aliased arguments with `is rw`.

One of the lesser known but useful tricks is to use this aliasing feature to create array refs of aliases

```
my ($x, $y) = (1, 2);

my $alias = sub {\@_}->($x, $y);

$$alias[1]++;  # $y is now 3
```

or aliased slices:

```
my $slice = sub {\@_}->(@somearray[3 .. 10]);
```

it also turns out that using `sub {\@_}->(LIST)` to create an array from a list is actually faster than 
 `[ LIST ]` since Perl does not need to copy every value.  Of course the downside (or upside depending on your perspective) is that the values remain aliased, so you can't change them without changing the originals.

As *tchrist* mentions in a comment to another answer, when you use any of Perl's aliasing constructs on `@_`, the `$_` that they provide you is also an alias to the original subroutine arguments.  Such as:

```
sub trim {s!^\s+!!, s!\s+$!! for @_}  # in place trimming of white space
```

Lastly all of this behavior is nestable, so when using `@_` (or a slice of it) in the argument list of another subroutine, it also gets aliases to the first subroutine's arguments:

```
sub add_1 {$_[0] += 1}

sub add_2 {
    add_1(@_) for 1 .. 2;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is all documented in detail in [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html). For example:

> Any arguments passed in show up in the array @_.  Therefore, if you called a function with two arguments, those would be stored in $_[0] and $_[1].  The
>   array @_ is a local array, but **its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters**.  In particular, **if an element $_[0] is updated, the
>   corresponding argument is updated (or an error occurs if it is not updatable)**.  If an argument is an array or hash element which did not exist when the
>   function was called, that element is created only when (and if) it is modified or a reference to it is taken.  (Some earlier versions of Perl created the
>   element whether or not the element was assigned to.)  Assigning to the whole array @_ removes that aliasing, and does not update any arguments.

Comment: Somebody should mention that aliasing is transitive, such as with `for(@_) { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$// }`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl passes arguments by reference, not by value.  See http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlsub.htm

Comment: +1, but with the addition that the reference breaks if the OP instead writes `my $notref = $_[0]; $notref = 'UNCHANGED!';` This (and the added benefit of readable names) is why most subroutines start by assigning all the items in `@_` to named variables.

Comment: The document you link to hasn't been updated since 2003, which predates 5.8.8, often considered the earliest "recommended allowed" version of Perl. Much of it is still accurate, but there will be some situations where syntax has been changed or improved.

Comment: Try the latest persub at: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html or it you want an older version: http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlsub.html